# Scroll bar in an Item Renderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have an item renderer with an HBox with the scroll bar showing.
Because the scroll bar is in the ItemRenderer of a TileList when a user drags the slider it triggers the click event on the TiLeList.
Is there anyway to maybe stopPropogation of the events on the scroll bar only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a click handler like this for the HBox should work:

```
private function hbox_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void 
{   
    if(event.target.parent is ScrollBar)    
       event.stopPropagation(); 
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. It gets into the if statement, but it still does not stop the TileList from getting the event.

Comment: Accepted the answer. It started to work. Not sure why it didn't work at first I had left the code in and left it alone and now it works. So whatever, Thanks